# Sharing a large dataset between Nodejs Worker Threads

Tags: node.js

Inside my nodejs server, I need to perform CPU Intensive computation on a large dataset that comes from a SQL Server database. I've been reading about Worker Threads as a way to process my data in parallel, since I need to finish all my computation as fast as possible.

I have about 50 different mathematical operations needed to be performed on the same dataset. In no way I'm modifying the dataset as I do the operations, and the workers don't depend on other workers results to calculate theirs.

What is the best approach to sharing this huge SQL table inbetween all my workers? I was thinking about querying the data on the main thread and then storing somewhere where it could be acessible by every worker thread, but couldn't figure out quite so how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

NodeJs doesn't have the concept of threads as it is single-threaded, you can achieve the same using C++ and [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html)

The non-C++ approach would be to spawn multiple processes to do this.

SQL -> [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to main thread -> [spawn multiple processes from main thread](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) -> [pass the data to the child processes via IPC](https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917) -> on receiving data each process can start processing

You can also rely on [Pub-sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) for the same.

SQL -> the main process -> publish event with the data-set -> have multiple subscribers to do the designated operations.

[RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) is one option, there are many free and paid message brokers available.

However, there is a maximum limit on the message data that you can publish and these vary.

hope this helped you in some way :)  cheers